# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 78: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8

I have the following code in Python for a connection to a database in Postgre:

```py
engine = create_engine('postgresql://'+user+':'+passw+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+database)
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname='+database+' '+'user='+user+' '+'host='+host+' '+'port='+port+' '+'password='+passw)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

And it's giving me the following answer:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 78: invalid continuation byte
```

Is there any way to ignore the errors or change the character encoding?

Comment: It wouldn't be great to ignore the error, especially with database connection, but likely 2 options are as you said to  change the encoding or change the input which seems to be causing the error. If you dont have control over changing the encoding then ensure your inputs are correct

Comment: Perhaps the PostgreSQL server encoding is `SQL_ASCII`. In that case, there is no remedy.